# Unable to extend typings of sinon

Tags: typescript, sinon, typescript-typings

I'm having trouble getting [sinon-stub-promise](https://github.com/substantial/sinon-stub-promise) to work with typescript. The definition file in `@types/sinon-stub-promise` lacks the default export. I followed the [docs on declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) closely but it doesn't compile.

Compile Error:

```
index.ts(4,18): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof 'sinon'' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SinonSandbox'.                                            
  Property 'clock' is missing in type 'typeof 'sinon''.                                                                                                           
index.ts(6,25): error TS2339: Property 'stub' does not exist on type 'typeof 'sinon''.
```

Sinon's definition file:

```
declare namespace Sinon {
  // ...

  interface SinonStubStatic {
    (): SinonStub;
    (obj: any): SinonStub;
    (obj: any, method: string): SinonStub;
    (obj: any, method: string, func: any): SinonStub;
  }

  // ...

  interface SinonFakeTimers {
    now: number;
    create(now: number): SinonFakeTimers;
    setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, timeout: number, ...args: any[]): number;
    // ...
  }

  interface SinonSandbox {
    clock: SinonFakeTimers;
    // ...
    stub: SinonStubStatic;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Adjusted [sinon-stub-promise](https://github.com/substantial/sinon-stub-promise) typings:

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/sinon-stub-promise/sinon-stub-promise.d.ts
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/sinon/index.d.ts" />
declare module 'sinon' {
  interface SinonPromise {
    resolves(value?: any): void;
    rejects(value?: any): void;
  }

  interface SinonStub {
    returnsPromise(): SinonPromise;
  }
}

// Added by me, because this is missing in the typings on dt
declare module 'sinon-stub-promise' {
  function setup(sinon: Sinon.SinonSandbox): void;
  export = setup;
}
```

index.ts

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');

sinonStubPromise(sinon);
```

Minimal sample repo: https://github.com/marvinhagemeister/typings-bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that typings for `sinon` have `export` at top level, at the very end of `@types/sinon/index.d.ts` file:

```
declare var Sinon: Sinon.SinonStatic;

export = Sinon;
```

Which seems to make it impossible to extend using ambient modules.

But it's doable if you make all the modules external as well, however I have no idea how to make it work with typings (distributing it as `@types` on the other hand seems possible).

Put this in the `sinon.d.ts` file next to your `index.d.ts` (this is how you declare an extension for external `sinon` module - all interfaces will be merged):

```
import "sinon";
declare module "sinon" {

    export interface SinonPromise {
        resolves(value?: any): void;
        rejects(value?: any): void;
    }

    export interface SinonStub {
        returnsPromise(): SinonPromise;
    }

    // had to add these from SinonSandbox to SinonStatic
    // 
    // no idea if it's really supposed to have those methods
    export interface SinonStatic {
        requests: SinonFakeXMLHttpRequest;
        server: SinonFakeServer;
        useFakeServer(): SinonFakeServer;
        restore(): void;
    }
}
```

Put this in the `sinon-stub-promise.d.ts` file next to your `index.ts`:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

declare function setup(sinon: sinon.SinonSandbox): void;

export = setup;
```

Then, in your `index.ts`

```
// in order to use your extension you have to import both here
import * as sinon from "sinon";
import "./sinon";


import sinonStubPromise = require("./sinon-stub-promise");

sinonStubPromise(sinon);

const mkdirStub = sinon.stub()
  .returnsPromise().resolves(null);
```

The generated javascript code looks good:

```
"use strict";
var sinon = require("sinon");
var sinonStubPromise = require("sinon-stub-promise");
sinonStubPromise(sinon);
var mkdirStub = sinon.stub()
    .returnsPromise().resolves(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Unfortunately I still get the same error: `index.ts(6,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sinon-stub-promise'.`

Comment: Here is example repo that compiles without errors https://github.com/fictitious/typings-bug

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that one can import `*.d.ts` files directly!